# sinon.js fake server responses

Tags: javascript, sinon

I created a fake server and would like to do it two things in the end:

- answer to a request
- check the passed data

This works this way:

```
    server.respondWith("POST", serverUri, [ 200, {"Content-Type": "application/text"}, "Answer from fake server" ]); // f1
    server.respondWith(function(data) { // f2
            try {
                var dataSentToServer = data.requestBody;
                ok(dataToRegister === dataSentToServer, testComment);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
    );
```

But at the beginning of the test I don't want it to response. So I simply leave f1 away.
But after some statements I want the server to call f1 and f2. Just adding the line of f1 now doesn't work because f2 is then not called any more. It seems that f1 overwrites f2. I would need to redeclare f2 as well.

Is there a possibility to add behaviour to already existing respondWith() functions?

Answer (score 0):

It's similar task of my fake-server test. You must leave one function respondWith and write inside all logic of data and answers of server.

```
   server.respondWith(method, model,

    (function() {

      var answer = [];

      if (model.attributes.car_model == "") {
        answer = [
          404,
          { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          '[{"0":"not car selected"}]'
        ];
      } else {
        answer = [
          200,
          { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          '[{"0":"good query"}]'
        ];
      }

      return answer;

    })(model));
```

Where 'model' - is you data from ajax, in if-else blocks you verify your data and sent necessary answer to browser.